# easypng alternative/super simple data visualisation library (c++)

Tags: c++, data-visualization

I happened across easypng as a way of displaying data for some machine learning projects I am attempting.

However it is completely out of date having not being maintained since 2009 and i cannot compile it.

Are there any alternative libraries (ideally platform agnostic) that allow a program to write a pixel in such a straight forward way such as

```
writepixel(x,y,colour)
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you forced to use the PNG file format? You could write to a PPM file (you don't even need a library) and then use ImageMagick to convert it to PNG.

Comment: You can create images on pixel basis with `Qt` and `QImage/QPixmap`. `Qt` programs can be compiled for `Linux`, `MacOS` and `Windows` (and possibly others).

Comment: no i'm not restricted to png thanks @Blender - hochl i'll try qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used QT in the end ass suggested by hochl